# When calling the value of objects from JSON, why must it be enclosed in quotations and plus symbols?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, annotations

When first trying to make this call to the PunkAPI, I was trying to append images (urls are an object returned in the JSON) with

```
append("<img src='beer[i].image_url'/>");
```

Which did not work because (from console) a request was being made to http://projectURL.com/beer[i].image_url instead of http://apiURL/beer[i].image_url.

I saw from an online example that it will work properly if I enclose the object request in quotes and pluses:

```
append("<img src='"+beer[i].image_url+"'/>");
```

What I would like to know is **why** the pluses and quotes are required.  Thanks in advance!

Full code below

```js
 var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  
request.open("GET", "https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers?abv_gt=5"); 
  request.responseType = 'json';
  request.send();
  
  request.onload = function() {    
    var beer = request.response; 

    var i; 
    for(i=0; i<beer.length; i++){ 
      $("#demo").append("<img src='"+beer[i].image_url+"' />");
    }    
  };
```

```html
    <body>
  
  <div id="demo">
    
  </div>
  
</body>

  
 <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: The right way to do this is `$("#demo").append($("<img>", {src: beer[i].image_url}))`, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that if you do not use quotes and pluses to concatenate the string, then JavaScript will not know you are trying to concatenate the variable value to use it as part of the final string and will interprete it just as a simple string.

So you need to concatenate the variable as follows:

```
append("<img src='"+beer[i].image_url+"'/>");
```

Or in es6 you could use the variable replacement using backticks quoted strings:

```
let source = beer[i].image_url;
append(`<img src="${source}" />`);
```

Comment: es6 is not well supported in IE11 and relying on it for mass production is a bit risky, but your example is correct

Comment: @Reflective i know, I only wrote it as as a "how to in es6".

Comment: Ah thank you!  Was only vaguely familiar with the concept of concatenation.

Comment: I know, wrote the comment to warn the guy of something which he may experience lately. it's good that you showed another possibility. I'm always a step away to use this way as it is natural to many other languages, but I'm stopping myself because people are still using very exotic browsers as IE8 per instance, especially in corporate environment.

Comment: That’s why there are transpilers around @Reflective

Comment: @Reflective i think is good to put both possibilities. I explained the question giving a valid answer, and as a side note I quickly described how this could be achieved in es6. If we relay on such a deprecated browser as IE8 we’re never going to move forward. Anyway i accept your point, but I disagree on not giving other options as part of the answer.

Comment: it's a big discussion which is better - to write a compatible code or to use tools for compatibility ... bot have advantages and disadvantages depending on the project.

Comment: @Reflective totally agreed with that :-)

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing in JavaScript as variable binding inside a double quoted strings. Even there was usually a simple var could be used, but not an expression as you want to bind `beer[i].image_url`